# What happens when I trade away my Rotom formes?

Tags: pokemon-fourth-generation

In Pokemon Platinum and HeartGold/SoulSilver, there are rooms where Rotom can possess household appliances to gain alternate formes. The appliance is removed from the room while Rotom is in that forme.

When I trade the Rotom away, does my Rotom's Room get its appliance back? Does this differ between versions of the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Rotom automatically reverts to its original form when traded.

Rotom's appliance forms are only available in Platinum, HG/SS, and B/W.

Comment: ... and X/Y. Let's just say they're available in every game starting with Platinum.