# Can I have two Rotoms with the same forme on the same team?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation, pokemon-fourth-generation

According to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41016/what-happens-when-i-trade-away-my-rotom-formes), if Rotom is possessing an appliance when traded, Rotom reverts to its original forme, and the appliance returns to the Rotom's Room.

Is it possible to have, for example, two Frost Rotoms (two Rotoms both possessing a refrigerator) on the same team somehow, without cheating?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dusted off my old copies of Pokémon Diamond, Platinum, and SoulSilver to test this. When you enter a trade in the Union Room, every Rotom in your party turns into a normal-forme Rotom, even if it isn't being traded to another game. The appliances get returned to the room in each respective game. I suppose Gamefreak anticipated this issue and implemented this to make sure people wouldn't run into any same Rotom-forme problems.

---

It's not possible to have two Rotom of the same forme. When you choose an appliance to turn Rotom into a specific forme, the appliance then disappears (until choosing a different forme), so there wouldn't be a way to have two of the same forme in your game without cheating.

Comment: Have you actually tested this? The question is pretty much asking whether the appliance will return to the room if you receive a rotom with that forme in a trade, even if you have have another rotom with that forme already.

Comment: @MrSmooth If a Rotom is being sent in a trade, it will turn into normal-forme Rotom during the trade, the appliance will be returned to the room of the person trading the Rotom away, and the recipient will get a normal-forme Rotom.

Comment: Exactly, what he's asking is if he can then take the normal rotom, and take it to the appliance that was returned (say the fridge) and turn it back into that forme rotom, even if he already has a rotom with that same forme. So unless you've actually tested trading a rotom, or someone has tested and documented this, you can't just assume that you can't have two rotoms of the same type.

Comment: *In your own game*, an appliance disappears when you use it.  It doesn't matter where the second Rotom came from because it'll always start in Normal Forme.  You can't use the same appliance twice, and you can't use other peoples appliances.  This is not complicated at all.

Comment: @MrSmooth I tested it and updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's kinda late, but in 4th generation games, we can't have rotom with same form at once. But in 5th and 6th generation games we can have multiple rotom with same form in one game.

> Unlike Rotom's Room, these locations do not have five separate
>   appliances; instead, a single box has the power to change Rotom's
>   form. 
>   **This allows multiple Rotom to share the same form in one game, as well as being tradable in all forms.**

[Source](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Rotom%27s_Room#Other_appliance_locations)